# Can I use Cursor Adapter with a GridView in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am building a picture app with a link to descriptions. Would a `GridView` `RecyclerView` with a Cursor adapter be a suitable way to do this as using the Movie database as a source for the movie thumbnails and description data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find cursor adapter implementation in below link I also put code below link , it may help you.

[Recycler view with cursor adapter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121353/recycler-view-with-cursor-adapter)

First of all CursorAdapter is not designed for use with a RecyclerView. You are trying to hack something in there that would never work right. You can't just call it's methods and expect it to function correctly. See the source.

So first things first. We want to use a cursor.. lets separate off this responsibility and create the  RecyclerViewCursorAdapter. It's what it says, a CursorAdapter, for a RecyclerView. The details of this are pretty much the same how CursorAdapter works. See its source to see what is the same and what is not.

Next, we now have your original class RVAdapter to implement the abstract RecyclerViewCursorAdapter which requires us to implement onCreateViewHolder and our new onBindViewHolder which gives us a Cursor parameter to bind against. The details of these views are the same as your original just tidied up a little.

RVAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Random;


public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<RVAdapter.ProductViewHolder>
{
    private static final String TAG = RVAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private final Context mContext;
    private final Random mRandom;


    public RVAdapter(Context context, String locationSetting)
    {
        super(null);
        mContext = context;
        mRandom  = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Sort order:  Ascending, by date.
        String sortOrder = ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC";
        Uri productForLocationUri = ProductContract.ProductEntry
            .buildProductLocationWithStartDate(locationSetting, System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Students: Uncomment the next lines to display what what you stored in the bulkInsert
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver()
            .query(productForLocationUri, null, null, null, sortOrder);

        swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor)
    {
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(ShopFragment.COL_PRODUCT_IMAGE);
        String price = cursor.getString(ShopFragment.COL_PRODUCT_PRICE);

        holder.productPrice.setText("US $" + price);

        int height = mRandom.nextInt(50) + 500;

        //Download image using picasso library
        Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(imagePath)
            .resize(500, height)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(holder.productPhoto);
    }


    public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        CardView cv;
        TextView productPrice;
        ImageView productPhoto;

        ProductViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            productPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            productPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_photo);
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewCursorAdapter.java

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * RecyclerView CursorAdapter
 * <p>
 * Created by Simon on 28/02/2016.
 */
public abstract class RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>
{
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private boolean mDataValid;
    private int mRowIDColumn;


    public RecyclerViewCursorAdapter(Cursor cursor)
    {
        setHasStableIds(true);
        swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    protected abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, Cursor cursor);

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position)
    {
        if(!mDataValid){
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }
        if(!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        onBindViewHolder(holder, mCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        if(mDataValid && mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            return mCursor.getLong(mRowIDColumn);
        }
        return RecyclerView.NO_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        if(mDataValid && mCursor != null){
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    protected Cursor getCursor()
    {
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor)
    {
        Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
        if(old != null){
            old.close();
        }
    }

    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor)
    {
        if(newCursor == mCursor){
            return null;
        }
        Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if(oldCursor != null){
            if(mDataSetObserver != null){
                oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
        }
        mCursor = newCursor;
        if(newCursor != null){
            if(mDataSetObserver != null){
                newCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
            mRowIDColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else{
            mRowIDColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }


    private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver = new DataSetObserver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChanged()
        {
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated()
        {
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```